# Patching Lucene to run in an unsigned applet

Tags: java, javascript, security, lucene, applet

I'm trying to get [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) working in an unsigned applet. The motivation is that we only have access to a user's plaintext data on the client-side and are trying to build a search and indexing facility for apps without a trusted server. The idea is that documents will be pushed into the lucene applet using javascript, indexed and then exported as an opaque blob that can be encrypted client-side and then pushed to an untrusted server for storage. For search, the index will be downloaded, decrypted and loaded into the applet. We're generally expecting very small indices.

So, the problem: It seems I can't instantiate an *IndexWriter* without mysterious, bad things happening. From the javascript side (Chrome) I get an "Error calling method on NPObject."
From the Java console I get nothing; no apparent exception, no stack trace, nothing.

Before instantiating the *IndexWriter* I'm successfully instantiating a *RAMDirectory*, *IndexWriterConfig* and *StandardAnalyzer*, no problems there. My assumption is that something in the stack trace above *new IndexWriter(...)* is violating an applet security policy. I found some old Lucene [bugs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-369) reporting problems with System.getProperty() but they seem to have been patched ages ago. I'm building the most recent code as of August 8, 2011.

Does anyone know how I could get more detailed information from the JRE on what's causing the problem? (or, ever better, does anyone know which Lucene classes (if any) need to be patched for unsigned execution?) I'm developing using the sun SDK on linux.

PS: I would also be interested in any alternatives to Lucene with an applet as I'm not crazy about this solution.

Comment: I managed to get this working. Strangely, when you call a Java method from JavaScript and it ends up throwing a runtime exception, you don't get a stack trace in the Java console. When the trace originates Java-side you get a complete trace. In this case, it was a security problem. I had to patch org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterDeleteQueue to not use AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater and org.apache.lucene.util.Constants to not use System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"). Thanks to anyone who looked into this.